# log.io monitoring tool hosted in AWS EC2, cannot reach server after starting log.io-server

Tags: networking, server, aws, monitoring

Installed log.io in my Ubuntu 20.04 EC2 instance as given in the below documentation.

https://github.com/NarrativeScience/log.io

After npm install started server with `log.io-server`, terminal outputs

```
TCP message server listening on port 6689
HTTP server listening on port 6688
```

I tried to access the log.io http server in browser using EC2 Public IPv4 address on port 6688
Expected result
[expected logio server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgRZr.png)

The result is 'IPv4':6688 site can't be reached

In security group of EC2 instance 6688 , 6689 ports are open as custom TCP to 0.0.0.0

Comment: Have you confirmed that `ufw` is not blocking access? `sudo ufw status` will show you what ports are open, whether the service is running, or whether the tool is installed at all 

Comment: executed `sudo ufw allow 6688` to allow that port. still same issues